# Optimal strategy for selecting tags

Tags: discussion, tags

What is the correct/best/optimal strategy for selecting tags for my questions? Considering adding another 3-2 more specific tags to 2-3 major tags for a question, would this strategy improve targeting people, who might be interested in answering the question? Would it decrease the question's exposure or increase it? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't SEO; don't play games with the tags. Use the tags that apply to and accurately describe your question.

Comment: @CodyGray: I don't plan to trick the system. Rather I'd like to understand how it works so I could use its features with maximum efficiency for the benefit of the whole community.

Comment: Well, you sort of know how it works. You can search for and sort questions by tag. You can also "follow" a particular tag, and many users do this. So yeah, using more tags will increase visibility. But using inapplicable tags or otherwise mistagging the question will piss people off, which tends to backfire in your getting a good answer. What more is there that you were wanting to know? It seems pretty straightforward to me.

Comment: @CodyGray: It wasn't that straightforward to me, hence my question. Sorting, following and searching for tags is clear. Using appropriate tags is certainly clear, too. What wasn't clear to me is situation, such as the following. Suppose a subset of people follow or search for two tags: a more general `git` and a relevant, but more specific `submodule`. The unclear to me part was/is whether using both tags (which I'd prefer and consider correct) would limit the exposure to only people, interested in **both** topics. (to be continued)

Comment: @CodyGray: (cont'd) A person, following just `git`, might intentionally or accidentally omit more particular tag, but he/she can still be the perfect candidate to provide an answer. If the system limits the exposure to people with interest in **both** topics, both me and that person are denied the opportunity to "complete the mission". Now I hope you understand my logic and reason for asking this question. It's not that trivial.

Comment: If the question is about git, then you should use the [tag:git] tag.  You might *also* use the more specific [tag:submodule] tag (or whatever else), if appropriate.

Comment: @CodyGray: I've already done that. My concern was not missing the exposure, as I explained above.